# "javascript:" as value of which HTML attributes

Tags: javascript, html

I saw that `"javascript:"` works as values ​​of the HTML attributes `href` and `action`.

Apart from the opportunity of this solution, and regardless of the fact that there are event attributes (`onclick`, etc.), does `"javascript:"` work with other HTML attributes?

(for example, the HTML title attribute displays it as "plain text")

```html
<a href="javascript:alert('href');">LINK</a>

<form action="javascript:alert('action');">
    <button type=submit>button</button> <!--(it works in some web browsers) -->
</form>

<p title="javascript:alert('title');">title</p>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`javascript:` is a *pseudo-protocol* which you can use essentially anywhere you can put a URL. That's why it works in `href` on `a` elements and `action` on `form` elements, which are attributes in which URLs are expected, and not in `title`, which isn't expected to contain a URL. But having just tried it on an `img`'s `src` and had it not work (in Chrome), I wouldn't be surprised if some URL attributes are locked down. It may well only be ones with an associated activation from a user event where browsers run the code.

That said, you've identified just about the only two places where it would be *useful*. :-)

Comment: > you can use essentially anywhere you can put a URL
Thanks, so it should theoretically works with `cite`, `data`, `formaction`, `icon`, `poster`, `src`, `srcset` too.

Comment: > That said, you've identified just about the only two places where it would be useful. :-)

Thanks. I understood :-)

Comment: @Juri: Re those attrs: Maybe. I suspect you'd need something where the URL is triggered by a user event (see my note about `img` `src`).